# Object following path angle in blender 2.9?

Tags: animation, filmic-blender

I am new to Blender and can't figure out how to achieve an animation like this:

[image]

Comment: you mean just the object rotating on itself?

Comment: not rotating object but the sides of object like the link i attach

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? Perhaps watching some tutorials about animation could help :).

Comment: thanks for your help. i have done it.